# How to connect LED's in nesC?

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I am trying to understand how nesC's modules, configurations, interfaces, and components work.
To do this I have tried to implement a very simple application; when its done booting up, it should turn on its three LED's to show its ID.
But I get the error:

```
/home/tinyos/WSN-Project/src/CoolLed/CoolLedM.nc: In function `CL.setCoolLed':
/home/tinyos/WSN-Project/src/CoolLed/CoolLedM.nc:12: Leds.led0On not connected
/home/tinyos/WSN-Project/src/CoolLed/CoolLedM.nc:14: Leds.led0Off not connected
```

I have used the `Blink` and `BlinkToRadio` examples as guides, but have not seen each individual led connected.
So what does this error message mean?
And how do i fix this problem?

---

Here is my program with the comment showing in which file it is placed.

```c
// AppC.nc
configuration AppC{}
implementation{
    components AppM;
    components MainC;
    AppM.Boot -> MainC;
    components CoolLedM;
    AppM.CL -> CoolLedM;
}

// AppM.nc
module AppM{
    uses interface Boot;
    uses interface CoolLedI as CL;  
}
implementation{
    event void Boot.booted(){
        call CL.setCoolLed((uint8_t)TOS_NODE_ID);
    }
}

// CoolLedI.nc
interface CoolLedI{
    command void setCoolLed(uint8_t mask);
}

// CoolLedC.nc
configuration CoolLedC{}
implementation
{
    components CoolLedM;
    components LedsC;
    CoolLedM.Leds -> LedsC;
}

// CoolLedM.nc
module CoolLedM{
    provides interface CoolLedI as CL;
    uses interface Leds;
}
implementation{
    command void CL.setCoolLed(uint8_t mask){
        if(mask & 0x01)
            call Leds.led0On();
        else
            call Leds.led0Off();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that `CoolLedM` uses interface `Leds`, but the interface isn't connected to any implementation. Let's look at `AppC.nc`:

```
configuration AppC{}
implementation{
    components AppM;
    components MainC;
    AppM.Boot -> MainC;
    components CoolLedM;
    AppM.CL -> CoolLedM;
}
```

Indeed: you use `CoolLedM` in the application, but nothing defines what implementation of `Leds` that module uses.

You also define `CoolLedC`, which does wire the `Leds` interface of `CoolLedM`, but it has two issues:

- `CoolLedC` itself isn't used anywhere.
- `CoolLedC` doesn't provide any interface, so it can't really be used.

To immediately fix, your problem, wire `Leds` in `AppC` like you did in `CoolLedC` (and delete unused `CoolLedC`):

```
    components LedsC;
    CoolLedM.Leds -> LedsC;
```

A better and more common design (see the links below) is to define `CoolLedC` as a self-contained module that provides the `CoolLedI` interface. I recommend starting with some tutorial to learn more about nesC and TinyOS:

- http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TinyOS_Tutorials
- http://csl.stanford.edu/~pal/pubs/tos-programming-web.pdf